# Pandas filepath includes a single quote

Tags: excel, pandas

I'm trying to read an excel file from a directory path that includes a single quote and it's causing me problems. Any ideas on how to get around it. Say the filepath is c:\users\me\excel\actual's\test.xlsx. I can't change the path name and remove the quote, I need to be able to work around the single quote

```
import pandas as pd
import os
download_dir = r'c:users/me/excel/actual's'
os.chdir(download_dir)
lst = os.listdir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use " instead?

```
download_dir = r"c:users/me/excel/actual's"
```